# iOS 8 today widget snapshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I'm developing a today widget displaying some personal information about the user using it.
According to Apple documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1)) the system captures snapshots of today widget's view.

> To help your widget look up to date, the system occasionally captures
>   snapshots of your widget’s view. When the widget becomes visible
>   again, the most recent snapshot is displayed until the system replaces
>   it with a live version of the view.

Form security reasons and data integrity I was asked for the following questions :

1. Where are the snapshots being saved ?
2. Does anyone has access to those snapshots being saved by OS ?

Thanks ...

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the snapshots are being stored in the system somewhere and only the system has access to them (assuming the device isn't jailbroken or something).

Comment: Storage locations are not documented, and there's no API to access the snapshots. Whether they're secure is impossible to answer without significant reverse engineering work.